# Comment author url link is wrong? How to change from authors/ to author/

Tags: permalinks, redirect, htaccess, comments

I’m maintaining a rather simple blog where a small number of people are registered as administrators to write posts. When making a link to the authors URL in a posts meta data, I use the function

```
get_author_posts_url(authorid).
```

This links to e.g. `mydomain.com/author/bill`
This is the correct URL for the author Bill. Now I’ve just discovered that when one of the admins create a comment to a post, the author comment URL link reference to the wrong URL. If same author, Bill, makes a comment to a post, the link is:
`Mydomain.com/authors/bill` (with an **s** behind author). This is wrong and when following this URL it gives me a 404 error.

I’ve tried different methods to overcome this, trying to create my own callback comment function, tried to create a custom rewrite function and such but nothing has worked. Initially I don’t understand why the comment author URL is different but that’s another question.

Any help or suggestions to solve this small, but very much annoying problem would be appreciated.

Thanks
- Mestika

Comment: maybe show the code excerpts that generate the wrong URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you may be over-thinking this. I don't use comment author URLs very often, but if I'm not mistaken, the URL for the author of a comment is usually the website URL the user has set in their profile.

I had the same issue once. The author didn't have his own website, so he wanted his comments to link to his profile page on the website... But he entered the URL incorrectly.